# svg hover and click on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, svg

On desktop `onmouseover` it changes color to green and then I `click` it changes to red but in mobile devices both event goes at the same time. Is it possible to make on tap changes to green color then on 2nd tap it goes to red color?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="800" height="600" version="1.1" style="display:inline">
  <g>
<rect id="rect1" x="160" y="10"
width="60" height="60"  fill="blue"
onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('fill','blue');"
onclick="evt.target.setAttribute('fill','red');"
onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('fill','green');"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/LzqL9/4/)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right behavior on touch devices usability-wise would be to color the `rect` green when the touch starts, if the user drags the finger off the `rect` then it would go back to blue. If the user releases at the same target it would change the color to red. This behavior could be replicated with CSS (removing your `onmouseout` and `onmouseover` handlers):

```
rect {
  fill: blue;
}

rect:active {
  fill: green
}
```

Now, if you really want it to behave in the way you describe (first tap is green, second tap is red) then you'd have to keep the state somewhere (in the DOM?) which complicates things, from the top of my mind I'd try...

```
ontouchend="evt.target.getAttribute('data-clicked') === "true" ? evt.target.setAttributed('fill', 'red') : evt.target.setAttribute('data-clicked', 'true')";
```

The problem with this is that you can start the touch at a different point and end the touch at the `rect` element.